# Virtual Directory accessible from IIS, but not from website

Tags: iis, url-rewriting, virtual-directory

I am completely new to IIS and would like to host a website with a virtual directory.
I've got a working website A with domain https://mydomain.lan:3002, hosted using IIS in C:\inetpub\wwwroot.
I would like to serve PDF files from outside this webroot, namely from a
network share located at \\mynetworkshare\pdffiles, mounted as Y:\.

Website A is created in IIS Manager right under "Sites". I added the virtual directory, pointing to the mounted folder, aliasing it as pdf.
I can browse the virtual directory under pdf in IIS Manager just fine.

When I want to access these files using the website (https://mydomain.lan:3002/pdf), I get 500.19 - Internal Server Error.
What do I need to do to make it work?

[image: Image of the server error]

Comment: The answer is easy, that IIS does not supported any mapped drives like your `Y:\`. You have to use UNC paths.

Comment: @LexLi The problem persists even when I use the UNC path.

Comment: Share a new screen shot please. It cannot be the same.

Comment: The error shows that something wrong in your web.config. So please show your web.config. And did you install url rewrite module? When you configured UNC, what's the app pool identity? Did it have read or write permission to UNC path?

Comment: I managed to fix it. It was a permissions problem where the IIS server user did not have read permission to the UNC path.